# Problema na função de procurar frases

Tags: c

Não estou descobrindo o problema que está na minha função, ela faz o seguinte:

- Eu recebo um vetor de char com o `'\n'` no final.
- Depois eu percorro o vetor verificando:
- Se encontrar no vetor o ponto de exclamação, ponto final, ou de interrogação, quer dizer que eu encontrei uma frase (frase foi definido como uma palavra que termina com um ponto uma exclamação ou uma interrogação), e guardo a posição do vetor;
- Se eu encontrar um espaço, eu simplesmente guardo a posição;
- Se eu encontro um dígito de 0 a 9, uma letra minúscula ou uma letra maiúscula, caso `i = 0`, parada recebe 0, senão, eu simplesmente guardo a posição de `i`;
- Se eu encontrar um `\n` eu termino o laço dando um `break`;

Bom, a função é essa, mas ela está dando um laço, o `i` trava dependendo da frase, mas não estou entendendo o porque dele estar travando, não estou achando o erro da lógica.

Segue abaixo o código da função:

```
int contagemFrases(char* p, int r) // Declaração da função que conta o número de frases presentes no texto.
{   
    int frases = 0, parada = 0, i;

    for(i = 0; i < r; i = parada + 1)
    {
        if(p[i] == 46 || p[i] == 33 || p[i] ==  63)
        {
            frases++;
            parada = i;
        }
        else if(p[i] == 32)
            parada = i;

        else if (p[i] >= 48 && p[i] <= 57 || p[i] >= 65 && p[i] <= 90 || p[i] >= 97 && p[i] <= 122)
        {
            if(i == 0)
                parada = 0;
            else
                parada = i;
        }
        else if(p[i] == '\n')
            break;
    }

    return frases;
}
```

Comment: Você que concorda que independente do (i == 0) a `parada` sempre vai receber `i`? Só uma observação, não é o problema

Comment: Mas o for esta percorrendo o vetor, então ele sempre guarda em parada a posição atual não??porque ela sempre esta guardando 1??

Comment: Pra que serve a `parada`?

Comment: Uma dica: o seu comentário do lado da função é redundante. Não precisa dele pra saber que tem uma declaração de função do lado :) Seria melhor fazer um comentário dizendo o que a função *faz*. O que significam os parâmetros de entrada? E o valor de saida? A função tem algum efeito colateral (como imprimir na tela ou mudar o valor de uma variável global)? Repare que falei "o que" e não "como", que é algo que o código C já consegue explicar sozinho. Tenho que confessar que não consegui entender ainda pra que serve a sua função...

Comment: Tem um exemplo de uma chamada de função onde o seu programa trava?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não entendi muito bem para que serve o `parada`, mas seu erro está exatamente nessa variável em relação aos `if/else`.

Fiz uns testes aqui e o problema acontece quando você não cai em nenhum `if/else` proposto, por exemplo quando a frase contém <kbd>vírgula</kbd>, dessa forma você nunca atribui ao `parada` o **novo** valor de `i`.

Minha sugestão seria você trocar

```
for(i = 0; i < r; i = parada + 1)
```

Para

```
for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
```

Que pra mim é o que faz mais sentido, ou então criar um `else` para incrementar a `parada` em último caso, simplesmente assim:

```
...
else {
    parada++;
}
```